Is there a stochastic version of the optical theorem?
In quantum field theory, when we study particle scattering, we have a unitary$S$-matrix, which connects asymptotic states, and we also have the optical theorem, which relates the imaginary part of the forward scattering amplitude to the total cross-section (crucially, a positive quantity because "probabilities sum up to 1").
The Källén-Lehmann spectral representation, expresses the propagator as an integral over a spectral density $\rho(\mu^2)$
$$
\Delta(p) = \int_{0}^{\infty} d\mu^2 \rho(\mu^2) \frac{1}{p^2 - \mu^2 + i\varepsilon}
$$
where $\rho(\mu^2)$ is positive due to the optical theorem.
Now, consider a stochastic process describing a particle in 1D. The phase space is $(x,t)$, and we can study transitions between different states. This seems analogous to quantum scattering, but I cannot connect the dots.
My questions are:

Is there an analog of the unitary S-matrix for stochastic processes? I understand we have transition probabilities, but is there a deeper mathematical structure similar to the S-matrix and the way we construct one particle states?
For stochastic processes, can we write a spectral representation similar to Källén-Lehmann? If so, what ensures the positivity of the spectral function?
Is there something analogous to the optical theorem that connects the imaginary part of some complex amplitude to a positive physical quantity?

